# Работа с HQL HIBERNATE

Tags: java, hibernate, intellij-idea, hql

Не понимаю в чем проблема.

есть такой вот запрос

```
   List<Service> list= super.getSession().createQuery(" from com.entity.Service ").list();
```

Он работает, но мне приходится указывать полный путь к классу. Как я понимаю, такого быть не должно. Если пишу просто "Service", то idea подчеркивает красным("Cannot resolve simbol"). Из-за этого я не могу написать сложные запросы.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего у вас не включена интеграции идеи и БД. Идея подчеркивает потому, что ничего не знает про схему вашей базы.

В левом столбце снизу (левее дерева файлов) у вас должны быть вкладка `Persistence`. Откройте её, там должно быть имя ваше БД. ПКМ на ней и `"Assign Data Sources..."`

В открывшемся окне слева надо указать коннект к БД и сохранить.

---

Если вкладки Persistence нет, тогда :

- Ctrl + Shift + Alt + S
- Facets
- добавить `jpa` и внизу выбрать `Default JPA provider` - `Hibernate`

---

По факту даже не делая этого у вас все должно работать, если все сделали правильно. Т.к. это ошибка интеграции `Intellij IDEA` а не проекта

Comment: Спасибо. Я просто думал, что оно не скомпилируется, но нет - работает. Только почему-то, когда нажимаю "Assign Data Sources", не выводится никаких доступных sources, хотя к базе данных через идею подключился.

Comment: @andreyatake подключение активно в данный момент?